# Move the startup screen boot menu

Tags: grub2

How do I center the startup screen boot menu on my monitor and make the text bigger? I recently tried kde neon - their boot menu was centered on my monitor.

kde grub uses a theme to accomplish centering - while my Ubuntu 20.04 grub does not. I need to write a grub theme.

Searched "grub themes" in search engine - found a lot of themes you can download and a page explaining how to configure grub to use them:
https://github.com/AdisonCavani/distro-grub-themes#vendor-themes
you'll need to scroll down the page.